Update column with unique index avoiding duplicates SQL
I have 2 tables where I need to update one column with the records from the other table:
create table abc(id,b,c)as values
 ('ab1',     1,   null)
,('ab2',     2,   null)    
,('ab3',     3,   null)    
,('ab4',     4,   null)  ;
alter table abc 
   add constraint abc_c_uniq unique(c)
  ,add constraint abc_pk primary key(id);

create table def(id,e,f,fk) as values
 (1,     1,   'text1', 'ab1')
,(2,     2,   'text2', 'ab2')  
,(3,     3,   'text3', 'ab3')  
,(4,     3,   'text3', 'ab4') ;
alter table def
  add constraint def_pk primary key(id)
 ,add constraint def_fk_fk foreign key (fk) references abc(id);

I need to update the values of column c in table abc with values from f from table def. Column c has a unique constraint and there is duplicated values for column f in table def but with different foreign keys, when I try to run my query I got an error:

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "abc_c_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (c)=(text3) already exists.


Here is my query:
UPDATE abc
SET c = def.f
FROM def
WHERE abc.id = def.fk;


NB: Gently reminder before you run these code make sure you begin a transaction if it is a live db
So , I am more concerned with duplicates which Randy alluded too. How I went solving this would solely be on things I have done in the past.
Having said that, given that there might be multiple values for f in def.
We can gently use it to update by only using it once in update this would correspond to fk in abc.c and it also ensures that we filter out duplicates in fk values from table def by either using the first or any record such as ID or f value in this case for each fk
A code snippet to guide you:
WITH f_pairs AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (defTable.f) defTable.fk, defTable.f
    FROM def AS defTable
    ORDER BY defTable.f, defTable.id 
)
UPDATE abc AS abcTable
SET c = f_pairs.f
FROM f_pairs
WHERE abcTable.id = f_pairs.fk;


Similar to @Randy's: you should actually be looking to reduce the number of fk's considered, not f's. Your example still causes a violation:
see this demo

Thanks both for the guidance code, I tried both, Min and Max with the subquery but with both I got same error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "abc_c_uniq"  since c has the unique constraint

@GeekDev I have updated it now, I missed a pain point which is an over sight

@Zegarek I don't know how you stop these things, thank you

Thanks @Zegarek this updated code guide works really good, thanks for the help

You need to decide what to do in the case where there are multiple values.. here is one choice
UPDATE abc AS abcTable
SET c = max( defTable.f )
FROM def as defTable
WHERE abcTable.id = abcTable.fk;


The idea is good but it won't work because it copied OP's erroneous WHERE abcTable.id = abcTable.fk; while it should likely be WHERE abcTable.id = defTable.fk; (there's no fk column in abc). Once that's fixed, you're left with ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in UPDATE. You could fix that with a CTE or subquery but you should actually be looking to reduce the number of fk's considered, not f's.

You can use a distinct on to pick only one def.fk to be used: demo at db<>fiddle
update abc
set c = payload.f
from (select distinct on(f)f,fk 
      from def 
      order by f,fk) as payload
where abc.id = payload.fk;

select * from abc;




id
b
c




ab4
4
null


ab1
1
text1


ab2
2
text2


ab3
3
text3



Otherwise, as the error suggests, you end up trying to use the two text3's from def for two different rows in abc, violating the unique constraint.

Another solution without using distinct on is by using the row_number in this way and the update will work as you expected:
update abc
    set c = (
          with flo as (
select a.*, row_number()over(partition by f order by e)as rn
from def a
          )
          select f from flo where abc.id = flo.fk and flo.rn=1
         );

Hope it helps.
